# Scenebuilder: ImageView inside Button is adding extra unwanted width to the button

Tags: java, intellij-idea, scenebuilder

Hope you all have been having a nice day. During the development of a chess game in IntelliJ and Scenebuilder, I encountered an issue where an ImageView in a button is causing th button to be stretched out. I am unable to change the width of the button whether it be by dragging the edges or changing the values in the Layout menu.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EIUn.png)[Button with image]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSoDl.png)[Button dimensions]

I have tried dragging the corners of the button to change the width, but nothing happened. I have tried editing the dimensions in the Layout menu but it did nothing. I have expermented by changing the width using code, but I was unable to find a successful method.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of troubleshooting, I believe I have figured out the answer to my own question. This is the solution in case there are others who struggle with this.

You must set both the padding and the label padding to 0 of the button. Then you must adjust the size of the image in the button after you have made these changes. This is what worked for me.

[image: settings of the button]